# Broadcast Receiver never called for WifiManager? (Android Wear)

Tags: android

I need to create an app to scan and gather the list of access points available, including the signal strength. For some reason every time I initiate the WifiManager.startScan() method, it returns true, but my Broadcast Receiver is never called.

Here is the code for my class:

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Manages radio (wifi) information
 */
public class NetworkManager {


    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    private WifiReceiver receiverWifi;

    private TextView mTextView;
    // true if scan is done
    private boolean mDone = true;
    private WifiManager mManager;
    List<ScanResult> results;
    // Data in form SSID, RSSI
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oldData = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<>();

    public NetworkManager(Context c, TextView mTextView) {
        this.mTextView = mTextView;

        mManager = (WifiManager) c.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (!mManager.isWifiEnabled())
            mManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();

        c.registerReceiver(receiverWifi,
                new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        if (mManager.isWifiEnabled() == false)
            mManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        scanAndSet();
        Log.d("TAG", "Constructor after scan and set");

        WifiInfo wifiInfo = mManager.getConnectionInfo();
        Log.d("TAG", wifiInfo.toString());
    }

    /**
     * Sets the SSID and RSSI from the scanned results into main data bin.
     */
//    private void setNetworkData() {
//        String result = "";
//        oldData = data;
//        data.clear();
//        for(ScanResult r : results) {
//            String ssid = r.SSID;
//            String rssi = String.valueOf(r.level);
//            HashMap<String, String> x = new HashMap<>();
//            x.put(ssid, rssi);
//            result += "ID: " + ssid + " - RSSI" + rssi + "/n";
//            Log.d("TAG", "R: " + result);
//        }
//        mDone = true;
//    }

    public void scanAndSet() {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.d("TAG", "Start: " + mManager.startScan());
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean isDone() {
        return mDone;
    }


    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("TAG", "On receive broadcast receiver");
            ArrayList<String> connections=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<Float> Signal_Strenth= new ArrayList<Float>();

            List<ScanResult> wifiList = mManager.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++) {
                connections.add(wifiList.get(i).SSID);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

the scanAndSet() method is suppose to initiate the scan. The startScan() method returns true. The receiver is only called when I go to the settings and the device searches for wifi networks, I can't seem to do it programatically.

Another peculiar thing is when I want to get information for the connected access point using `WifiManager.getConnectionInfo().toString()`, this is what it gives.

```
D/TAG: SSID: <unknown ssid>, BSSID: <none>, Supplicant state: COMPLETED, RSSI: -127, Link speed: -1Mbps, Frequency: -1MHz, Net ID: -1, Metered hint: false, score: 0
```

I'm completely lost, is this common with all Wear devices or is the wifi api disabled?